# php invoke class instance from dynamically generated string

Tags: php, string, class, instance, dynamically-generated

lets say I have a class named 'translations'.
I have an instance of the class called 'chinese_translations'

```
$chinese_translations = new translations;
```

Afterwards, I want to call this instance from a dynamically built string and I have tried several ways:

```
$part1 = 'chinese_';
$part2 = 'translations';
$instance_of_translations = ${$part1.$part2};
$instance_of_translations->getMsg();//Doesn't work
```

Also like this:

```
$part1 = 'chinese_';
$part2 = 'translations';
$instance_of_translations = $part1.$part2;
$$instance_of_translations->getMsg();//Doesn't work
```

I always get the "Call to a member function getMsg() on a non-object" message.
What I'm doing wrong?

*SOME ACTIONS TAKEN AND RESULTS OBTAINED:

```
//Lets see if the var is in scope:

echo $chinese_translations->getMsg(get_locale());//It works

$instance_of_translations = ${$part1.$part2};//Let's try to build the name dynamically

echo $chinese_translations->getMsg(get_locale()); //Call to a member function getMsg() on a non-object

echo $$chinese_translations->getMsg(get_locale()); //Object of class internal_message could not be converted to string in

var_dump($instance_of_translations);//It throws the following:

//object(internal_message)#1956 (1) { ["message"]=> array(2) { ["es_ES"]=> string(19) "The expected result" ["it_IT"]=> string(19) "The expected result" } }NULL
```

Comment: Your first example is working on my computer. Are you sure that the `$chinese_translations` is in the same scope like the part where you are calling `getMsg()`?

Comment: You were right, there was an scope issue!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$part1.$part2` is a string. Therefore, `$instance_of_translations` is the variable name, not the variable itself.

Try this:

```
$part1 = 'chinese_';
$part2 = 'translations';
$varName = $part1.$part2;
$instance_of_translations = $$varName;
var_dump($instance_of_translations);
```

It should reveal an object of type `translations`.

Read more about [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: This way I get the following output: "Class name must be a valid object or a string"

Comment: Both versions of your code work, mine works too. https://3v4l.org/QhHmP Maybe you have a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue (f.e. `$instance_of_translations` is a global variable and you try to access it in a function or method.)

Comment: There was an scope issue, sorry for your waste of time and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$className = $part1.$part2;
$instance = new $$className;
$instance->getMsg();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally the bracket version did the trick, but there was an scope issue so both answer maybe right. This one:

```
 $part1 = 'chinese_';
 $part2 = 'translations';
 $instance_of_translations = ${$part1.$part2};
 $instance_of_translations->getMsg();
```

Is currently working for me.